# Room | fails to insertAll

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

When I try to add multiple records, via

```
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    void insertAll(List<T> obj);
```

if one of the records has unique constraint error, it fails to insert the other record in the list as well.
Can't use the REPLACE on conflict, because it will cascade my previously created related table records.

I just need to insert multiple records, and if something is repeated, ignore that only. And keep adding the other records in the List.

Answer (score 0):

There was a different issue. When I looked for `MyTableDao_Impl.java`, I realised, for each record in the list, there is a different insert transaction.

And `OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE` ignores the current transaction only. So clearly this can't be the issue.